# Should i dispose a stringwriter? or reuse somehow?

Tags: .net

I'll make it simple. I have a stringwriter as a class member therefore i cannot use using(). I want an empty sw everytime i call a certain function. Should i call Dispose() on the sw and allocate a new object? or should i do something like .close() and do something else to empty the buffer?

Answer (score 13):

I agree with the other answerer, that you should look at your design to see if having the class level string writer is really the way to go.

However, I don't agree with the point about

> "All it does is call back into the
>   base class' (TextWriter) Dispose --
>   which does nothing."

When consuming classes, if a type implements `Dispose`, you really should call it, either explicitly or with a "using".

In this case, it is true that `StringWriter.Dispose` calls down to `TextWriter.Dispose` which does nothing, but I really wouldn't advise "just ignoring it".

The whole point of inheritance and polymorphism is that this type can be swapped out for a derived type.

Today's `StringWriter` in your code, may be swapped for tomorrow's `EvenBetterStringWriter` which may have a more meaningful implementation for `Dispose`.

If it implements `Dispose`, and you use it, you should seriously think about calling dispose when you are done.

Having privileged knowledge of the internals of this specific concrete implementation is dangerous when you let it guide your design like this. The author of the `StringWriter` class clearly meant for Dispose to be called, or it wouldn't be there.

Comment: +1. So you suggest i should just call dispose and create a new stringwriter each time? Theres no way to empty an existing one? (or maybe there isnt a benefit)

Comment: The problem with the re-use approach is, you've got other issues to consider: if you write a 1MB string, and then re-use it for a 2KB, does the other 1022KB sit there, un-freed, or does is it elligible for garbage collection? This is just one example. Overall - I'd probably go down the route of creating it every time, and only worry if there was a particular perfomance issue around doing this.

Comment: "The author of the StringWriter class clearly meant for Dispose to be called, or it wouldn't be there." - well, no. Dispose is there because StringWriter derives from the more general TextWriter.

Comment: Fair point - I should have been clearer with what I said. The author of *something in the StringWriter inheritance chain* clearly meant for Dispose to be called, or it wouldn't be there; but not necessarily the author of StringWriter itself.

Comment: I do not agree.  You say "The author of the StringWriter class clearly meant for Dispose to be called" which is not true. The real reason is because it inherits the abstract base class TextWriter which is used for other "Stream" based writers.   It is BAD practice to call code that does nothing.  Programming languages are ment to "process"; not to wait or do nothing.

Comment: It feels like you've misunderstood the point of polymorphism and the public interface of an object in object oriented programming. If you use a concrete type, you shouldn't have to peer into it using decompilation to work out what you can and can't do; you look at its public interface. In this case, the public interface implements IDisposable, so you should treat the class as such. You shouldn't be saying "I know this looks disposable but I know it isn't because I peeked inside.". The fact this implementation doesn't do anything is fine - that's the point. You should still call it.

Comment: I'd say Microsoft has misunderstood the purpose.  They made TextWriter implement IDisposable despite not using any unmanaged resources.  “Most of the subclasses happen to share this property” is a terrible reason to implement an interface, *especially* when that interface imposes significant complexity on anyone who uses any subclass.  If the public interface is a demonstrable lie, I don't feel terribly compelled to play along (and, from David's answer, I see that the O'Reilly book agrees).

Answer (score 5):

If you have a certain function that needs an empty StringWriter every time, why not just create a new StringWriter in that function?

But, getting back to your original question, I used [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to check out what StringWriter's Dispose does.  All it does is call back into the base class' (TextWriter) Dispose -- which does nothing.

So if you really need to "re-use" the StringWriter you're exposing, it looks like it would be safe to just re-create a new instance when you need it (although I think you should reconsider your design of exposing a StringWriter as a public member on a class).

Comment: i never said it was public ;). Its required for a callback and i cant pass in a stringwrite so it is a member.

Answer (score 2):

From O'reilly's C# in a nutshell:

> There are, however, three scenarios for not disposing:
>
> - ...
> - ...
> - When an object’s Dispose method is unnecessary by design, and disposing that object would add complexity to your program
>
> The third category includes the following classes: WebClient,
>   StringReader, String Writer, and BackgroundWorker (in
>   System.ComponentModel). These types are disposable under the duress of
>   their base class rather than through a genuine need to perform
>   essential cleanup. If you happen to instantiate and work with such an
>   object entirely in one method, wrapping it in a using block adds
>   little inconvenience. But if the object is longer-lasting, keeping
>   track of when it’s no longer used so that you can dispose of it adds
>   unnecessary complexity. In such cases, you can simply ignore object
>   disposal.

tl;dr: no, you don't need to dispose.