# Why do I need to call dispose on stringreader and stringwriter?

Tags: c#, idisposable

it begins with me reading a [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30329731/1831108)

`StringWriter` implments `public abstract class TextWriter : MarshalByRefObject, IDisposable`

on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) it says:

> The Framework provides the System.IDisposable interface that should be
>   implemented to provide the developer a manual way to release unmanaged
>   resources as soon as they are not needed.

but **what is considered as unmanaged resources?** I clearly don't think `StringWriter` qualifies. if I write my own without inheriting IDisposable....I don't see any need to add `Dispose()`

```
class ConfusedDevStringWriter{
   private StringBuilder sb;
   public ConfusedDevStringWriter(){ //ctor
      sb = new StringBuilder();
   }
}
```

And indeed I tested with visual studio memory debugger:
[image]
once the function returns, `StringWriter` and its `StringBuilder` are freed...**Moreoever, calling dispose seems to do nothing for StringWriter**...

[image]

So not every class that inherit from `IDisposable` has useful `Dispose`. Again this goes back to my question **what is considered as unmanaged resources (examples will be much appreciated n_n). I heard files are one of it...but isn't CLR a VM?...every resources should be managed by it, non?**

Comment: You question "*what is considered as unmanaged resources*" already has answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433197/what-exactly-are-unmanaged-resources

Comment: Question in title answered more or less in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234059/is-a-memory-leak-created-if-a-memorystream-in-net-is-not-closed (same Q about MemoryStream).

Comment: I closed it as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475228, which between that and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433197 answers both questions.

Comment: Don't understand why this question was closed. StringReader/StringWriter don't need to be disposed. From O'reilly's C# in a nutshell: " These types are disposable under the duress of their base class rather than through a genuine need to perform essential cleanup. If you happen to instantiate and work with such an object entirely in one method, wrapping it in a using block adds little inconvenience. But if the object is longer-lasting, keeping track of when it’s no longer used so that you can dispose of it adds unnecessary complexity. In such cases, you can simply ignore object disposal."

Answer (score 2):

`StringWriter` descends from `TextWriter`, which implements `IDisposable`, probably because *most* `TextWriters` will have unmanaged resources.  If you receive a `TextWriter` and you don't know where it came from (i.e. it might be any descendant of `TextWriter`), the fact that `TextWriter` implements `IDisposable` allows you to properly manage any unmanaged resources it has.  You can write code that accepts any `TextWriter`, calls `Dispose` when the writer is no longer needed, and trust that everything will get cleaned up OK.

Answer (score 0):

`StringWriter` inherits from the abstract `TextWriter`, which implements `IDisposable`, and has some subclasses that *do* have unmanaged resources like streams, file handles, etc.  So one can safely dispose of any subclass of `TextWriter` without having to worry about if the disposal is necessary or not.

So disposing of a `StringWriter` may not actually *do* anything (similar to `DataSet`), but it's still good practice to dispose of anything that implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: I do not agree. It is NOT a good practice to call code that does nothing. It is actually bad practice.  Programming languages are ment to "process"; not wait or do nothing.

Comment: @Darkonekt Are there any guarantees that a Dispose function will never do anything and not be needed for a disposable class on dotnet core, mono, any wasm implementation, and full framework for every version current, past and future? If there is some consortium that can ensure this then I would consider not wrapping these classes in using statements. If there is no guarantee then I think your last statement is a dangerous one to make.

Comment: @Darkonekt I missed this comment or I would have responded similarly to Theyouthis. `IDisposable` is a contract, where the owner is _expected_ to call `Dispose` when done with the object. The caller should make no assumptions about whether the method actually does anything or not. Plus, it's perfectly plausible that some custom subclass of `StringWriter` _does_ do something in it's `Dispose`, so if you choose not to cal it, you might introduce a resource leak.

Comment: @DStanley you are now wondering in the world of "what if".... The reality is that calling code that does nothing is not correct. It is superfluous.  And nothing demands that code needs to call every member of an interface. In this case in my opinion the interface is wrong because the object has no disposable objects so there is no need for it to implement such "contract".  Just because others do it wrong it does not mean one also has to.